# Master thesis mistakes with in-text citing and grammar

Tags: writing-style

I recently re-read my publicly available master's thesis which was made public a month ago. I found a lot of grammatical mistakes and also inconsistency of putting references in relation to interpunction.

1...and so on (50).
2....and so on. (50)

I feel ashamed as I managed to publish a lot of scientific articles in prominent journals, but with a short dead-line and exhaustion I made these mistakes in my master thesis.

How bad of an impact are these mistakes going to have on my reputation as a researcher and scholar? I'm currently working as a medical doctor.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/137789/what-should-i-do-if-i-find-a-mistake-in-my-submitted-masters-thesis

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/93505/i-found-a-huge-error-in-my-masters-thesis-which-i-defended-a-year-ago

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/126651/error-in-masters-thesis-i-do-not-know-what-to-do

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/200848/what-will-be-the-consequences-of-this-citation-error

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone at all will read your masters thesis once it's accepted.

Comment: I understand, but how bad of a mistake is it?

Comment: @BryanKrause That’s probably what Dr. Gay thought about her PhD thesis. But in principle I agree.

Comment: 35 downloads on my thesis have been made

Comment: I'm *hoping* you're not taking those download statistics (especially if they're provided by something like RG) at a face value. These are almost surely no 35 people who have downloaded and read your thesis. Not to throw shade on it, maybe it was outstanding, but this is just not what generally happens in academia. 35 reads on a paper in a month is truly breakthrough work.